# Inserting PHP variables in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

So I found this Pie Chart that I would like to use on my website (http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-types/html5-pie-chart/)

I've already adapted the code to where it establishes a connection to the MySQL database gets the information I need from and I've saved those as variables in PHP and displays them within the Pi chart. So far so good!

Now I've really like to make this a little bit more real-time as the information changes quite rapidly, so I was thinking, of having the jQuery update its information on a regular basis. Preferably every 1000ms or so. How would I go about achieving this?

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you will need to establish an ajax data flow:

- your main page will contain only the graph, but skip the data
- request the data by sending an ajax request to a separate page
- the data page should return your data object in JSON format (use `json_encode()`)

With [periodicalupdater](https://github.com/RobertFischer/JQuery-PeriodicalUpdater) you can update your data in the interval of your choice and automatically adjust this interval to reduce the load on your server.

Answer (score 1):

There's a worked example in the documentation: http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/how-to/live-updating-javascript-charts-json-api-ajax/

Basically, you need to use JavaScript and more specifically Ajax to query the server continuously and fetch new data in JSON format. Then update the chart using the brilliantly named 'updateChart' method. :)